# Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'O'

Tags: java

I'm sorry if this question has been posted, but I wasn't able to find an answer.

I've been watching thenewboston tutorials on youtube for java, and now I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'O'
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.conversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
at tuna.toMilitary(tuna.java:14)
at apples.main(apples.java:4)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, it's exactly as he has it (or at least I couldn't find anything different.

```
class apples{
public static void main (String[] args) {
    tuna tunaObject = new tuna();
    System.out.println(tunaObject.toMilitary());
}
```

---

```
public class tuna {
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;

public void setTime(int h, int m, int s){
    hour = ((h>=0 && h<24) ? h : 0);
    minute = ((m>=0 && m<60) ? m : 0);
    second = ((s>=0 && s<60) ? s : 0);

}

public String toMilitary(){
    return String.format("%O2d:%O2d:O2d", hour, minute, second );
}
```

Thanks a lot. (I do know one "}" is missing in each block of code)

Comment: any chance you are confusing zero 0 with the big o letter O ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `"%O2d:%O2d:O2d"`, replace `O` (the letter) by `0` (the number)

And as Cinnam mentionned, a `%` is missing.

The final format needs to be `"%02d:%02d:%02d"`

Comment: Also there is a missing `%` in the last part of the format string.

Comment: Yup, maybe eclipse changed how O's and 0's are written, now 0's have a bar in the middle and I thought it was an O. Also didn't see that missing 0. Thanks!